# Add tooltip to container when child is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm trying to accomplish is add a tooltip to a container div that wraps an input I'm disabling. Basically, a tooltip on disabled. Seeing that I can't do it on the disabled input I'm doing it on the container element.

I'm trying to add the tooltip to the container dynamically using this:

```
$('.input-group date').tooltip({'container':'body','placement':'top', 'trigger' : 'hover', 'title':'maximize'});
```

But it's not working.

On document.ready I do this:

```
$('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip() // Opt-in for tooltips
```

And the element itself looks like this:

```
<div class="input-group date" rel="tooltip">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dp1" style="width: 100px; vertical-align: middle" />
                                        <button class="input-group-addon" id="dp1Icon" onclick="return false" style="outline-style:none"><img src="<%=context%>/images/calendar-glyph.png"></button>
                                    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong? I think I have all the correct elements in place. Is there an easier way to assign a tooltip to a container element when its child input is disabled?

Am I making this more complicated?

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
$('.input-group date')
```

means "select all `<date>` elements that are descendants of elements with the `input-group` class".

Given that you said your markup was:

```
<div class="input-group date" rel="tooltip">
```

you presumably instead want:

```
$('.input-group.date')
```

i.e. "select all elements that have both the `input-group` and `date` classes"

TL;DR: Use a dot instead of a space in your selector

Comment: Thank you, very good catch. I really appreciate that. However, the tooltip is still not applied.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with using the show.bs.tooltip handler and testing if the component was disabled; if not, I'd prevent the default action a la:

```
// Set the tooltip for a start date that can't be edited (when mtg is in progress)
    $(".form-group.startDate").on("show.bs.tooltip",function(e){
        if ( !$("#dp1").is(":disabled") )
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```